# springboot cmd args contains special character

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, jar

`java -jar xx.jar --spring.datasource.password=root`  like this, if it don't contains special character, it is ok.

if `java -jar --spring.datasource.password='root!00'` , if contains special character `!`, it didn't work.  and I tried `\"root!00\"` `\'root\!00\'` `\"root\!00\"` and other ways , all field.

Comment: Did you try `java -jar '--spring.datasource.password=root!00'`? The quoting you're doing is to tell `bash` not to do anything with it. At the command-level, the entire `--` up to `00` is a single argument, and it is the argument that is [Bash-quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html). You should follow this link and read up on how Bash handles special characters.

Comment: You could also try escaping without quoting: `java -jar --spring.datasource.password=root\!00`

Comment: ✌      it's ok    , thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
java -jar --spring.datasource.password='root\!00'
```